# "ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist "

Tags: boot, lvm

When I boot up my server in **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop** .
I encounter this situation ,
after the screen tell you how to get into BIOS

[image]

Then

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problem:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

after I typed `exit` , system could always start normally.

I have searched and found out that there are many similar problems like mine . But the answers I have tried cannot solve my situation. I'm going to describe my server environment and what I have done as detailed as possible , very appreciate for any help . It really made me annoyed because I didn't do anything special before last shutdown .

I have installed Ubuntu system with LVM mechanism.
[image]

```
sudo parted -l
```

I took this screenshot when the system just setup several weeks ago.
[image]

```
lsblk
```

I have two disks , sdb is for another volume group , logical volumes on that vg are for KVM . I think it's not the matter , just mention.
[image]

I've followed the hints to inspect :

```
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) 
 - Check root= (did the system for the right device?)
```

what I've got

```
cat /proc/cmdline  
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu—vg-root ro rootdelay=30 quiet splash
```

As you can see , I've edited **/etc/default/grub** to add `rootdelay=30`, but it fixed nothing.

```
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)
```

Not really knowing what should I notice about this hint . When I list files in **/dev/mapper** , **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1** and **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root** are all there .

Other information that frequently asked to provide for similar problem :

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

[image]

```
blkid
```

[image]

I have entered into GRUB menu to boot with recovery mode , there are three pairs :

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-45-generic(recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42-generic(recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-38-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-38-generic(recovery mode)
```

But when I select any version in recovery mode to boot , just fail into BusyBox again . As I previously mentioned , after I type `exit` I could start system normally , but I don't think that I should do this every time , and it apparently my server have something wrong .

I really want to know  what behavior or situation could cause this problem ,then I could prevent it .

### LiveUSB boot environment :

`sudo parted -l`

[image]
[image]
[image]

`pvdisplay`

[image]

`vgdisplay`

[image]

`lvdisplay`

[image]
[image]

`lvmdiskscan`

[image]

Comment: have you tried booting with a livecd and using parted or similar to check for the existence of the underlying disk partitions. I have done this before when trying to format a disk and i accidentally overwrote my boot disk. usually the data is still there but the partition boundaries are not.

Comment: @Amias ,thanks for your response . Follow your tips, I have used liveusb to inspect disk partitions today. It seems that partitions are all normally there... I would append these information to the question .

Comment: i would expect the live environment to pick up the lvm  partitions , you might have to install lvm tools if it doesn't

Comment: I'm sorry that I 'm not sure what "pick up" means , you mean show what `lvdiplay` or `vgdisplay` output ?

Comment: yes , please post output of each command from live environment

Comment: @Amias,sorry for late, now they are appended to question .

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: hi did  you check the entries in  `/etc/crypttab`?

Comment: @Carr, Was you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @user.dz ,sorry for late response, just finish my mandatory military service
. The problem is still there, waiting proper time to move this server to dormitory and keep on trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Dell XPS-13 soon after a fresh Ubuntu 16.06 install, but was unable to successfully 'exit' BusyBox.

I powered the laptop on while holding ctrl, selected System Settings from the boot menu, entered 'SATA settings' and changed from RAID to AHCI

Apparently RAID harddrives aren't supported by Ubuntu

This immediately solved the problem for me

Comment: Worked on a Dell XPS 13 7390, running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Apparently it switched to RAID upon very low power, by itself (well there was a yellow, Support Assist warning screen I had to click "Continue" through, but still). Running Ubuntu from a flash drive on the machine didn't even show any other drives on it so I was really worried they were corrupted but this fixed everything perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your disks are fine and so it looks like somehow you have ended up with an initramfs has been made without lvm support.

try adding a new kernel and check the setup process closely for errors

Comment: Amias,really appreciate your help ,I would do what you advise and append more information if there is any new clue in the process .

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is quite old, I came across the same error message with a recent distro, namely Kubuntu 22.10.

### History

1. Debian 11 was installed on my brand new laptop. The encrypted LVM was created then. EFI and boot partitions are primary, unencrypted partitions. All other partitions are encrypted.
2. I just installed Kubuntu 22.10 in this LVM after I unlocked it in a terminal.
3. Then, the system wouldn't boot, issuing the same message as in the subject of this thread.

### My solution

During the boot process, I ended up in initramfs shell. From there, I could open the LUKS encrypted volume :

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0np13 nvme0np13_crypt
```

The last word in this command can be anything, but must be consistent with the file below.

Then, typing `exit` or Ctrl+D exits the shell and the boot process resumes. My system booted OK ! But not very pleasant to type this command at every boot, right ?

The thing is that initramfs doesn't know where to find the root file system. To fix this, in the running system, I created `/etc/crypttab` :

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=e4ae939c-74ff-43ac-8556-bdb8cf73f34d none luks,discard
```

The UUID is that of the **physical** partition where LMV is. To find it :

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

Once the file is created, run :

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Then reboot. In my case, it worked.